# How to install karaf features using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-karaf

I am trying to create a Dockerfile that will automatically install apache karaf and configure it to work and its working fine.

I want to install list of features. I can do it with below

```
docker exec -it 7447419c89da  /opt/karaf/bin/client
```

but I want to automate the process. What command can I run that will allow me to install the features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XML file ([Feature Repository](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/provisioning)] and copy it into *.../apache-karaf-4.1.5/deploy* folder. Then it will be picked-up by Karaf during start-time and features described in the file will be installed automatically if they have attribute specified: `install="auto"`.

Sample file:

```
<features
        name="AET Features"
        xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0 http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0">

    <repository>mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.2.0/xml/features</repository>

    <feature name="fooo" version="1.0.0" description="Features that should be installed" install="auto">
        <feature>cxf-core</feature>
        <feature>webconsole</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.features/4.1.2</bundle>
    </feature>

</features>
```

This will install new feature called *fooo* which consist of *cxf-core* feature - just for purpose of this example (this one needs its own repository location), the *webconsole* feature that is available on Karaf and additional bundle that provides a view of features in the Web Console.

To summarise:

1. Download and unzip [Karaf](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/karaf/4.1.5/apache-karaf-4.1.5.zip)
2. create a file with some name, i.e.:  `required-features.xml` with features description
3. Start Karaf instance

You can find examples of feature files in Karaf source, e.g.:

https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/assemblies/features/spring/src/main/feature/feature.xml

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** - pass the features as a parameter to the `client` as `docker exec -it 7447419c89da /opt/karaf/bin/client -r 7 "feature:install http; feature:install webconsole"`

I think that the [Witek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49434044/2013924) is correct and that is how it should work.

However when I was building [my own Dockerfile for iDempiere Micro on Karaf](https://github.com/iDempiere-micro/idempiere-micro-docker/blob/master/src/Dockerfile) to automatically install [Apache Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/), install other features (e.g. WebConsole) and deploy my bundles, I found out, that the only way how to achive this was:

1. install Apache Karaf in the Dockerfile, also include other helper shell scripts, do not try to install the features
2. start the docker with Karaf, let it boot and wait a while (on my testing environment it took up to 120s to be ready)
3. run `/opt/karaf/bin/client` as in your question and pass the required features as parameters as in `docker exec -i idempiere-micro-karaf /opt/karaf/bin/client -r 7 "feature:install http; feature:install http-whiteboard; feature:install war; feature:install webconsole"`
4. wait again, restart Apache Karaf using `docker exec -i idempiere-micro-karaf /opt/karaf/bin/client "system:shutdown -f -r"`

Comment: In point #2, you say "let it boot and wait a while". Could you update your post to specify the order of magnitude of time?